# rails 3.1 sphinx search hosting *thinking sphinx*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, sphinx

Firstly, Im a big fan of sphinx search. Thanks to sphinx.

Now my question is,

We are ready with a rails 3.1 app which uses sphinx search for full text searching.

Now, I know heroku is the best when it comes to rails hosting. It does not have support
for sphinxsearch, I hear.

If any of you know the right place to host a rails 3.1 app with sphinx search please
guide me.

I will mention the other things that Im using in my rails 3.1 app as listed in my gem
file.

```
#############################################################
source ' http://rubygems.org '

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.10'
gem "gritter", "1.0.1"
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.1.4'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
#############################################################
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: also consider trying the built-in postgres full text search https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Heroku does support Sphinx through the [Flying Sphinx](https://addons.heroku.com/flying_sphinx) add-on. Otherwise, any decent VPS should work for you. [Linode](http://www.linode.com), in particular, has a pretty good reputation.